# Hibernate Weblogic 10.3.4 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, weblogic

I'm running a weblogic 10.3.4 (Yes I know it a legacy version, but I'm not the one dictating the version...) on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

When deploying a JPA (hibernate) webapp on the server I get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:629)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:629)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I can see that ***MANY*** people have the same issue.

The official solution is found at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13720/using_toplink.htm#EJBAD1309
Which tells me to add:

```
#Enable JPA 2.0 functionality on WebLogic Server 10.3.4
export PRE_CLASSPATH=%BEA_HOME%\modules\javax.persistence_1.0.0.0_2-0-0.jar;%BEA_HOME%\modules\com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-0.jar
```

to WL_HOME/common/bin/commEnv.sh

This didn't work

My weblogic.xml is a following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

I also tried many other versions there as, some have add issues with the above of e.g. [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990633/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-spi-persistenceunitinfo-getvalida)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <container-descriptor>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
 </container-descriptor>
```

That instead gives me:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'administration-gui.war'
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:393)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:180)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:518)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: weblogic.deployment.EnvironmentException: Error processing persistence unit Offer of module administration-gui.war: Error instantiating the Persistence Provider class org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence of the PersistenceUnit Offer: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.getPersistenceProvider(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:375)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:393)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:386)
    at weblogic.deployment.BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(BasePersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:158)
    at weblogic.deployment.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:39)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: You probably have the wrong jar file on your classpath or two versions of the same jar... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167945/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-spi-persistenceunitinfo-getvalida

Comment: We are already using hibernate-jpa-2.0-api, as suggested in the link

Comment: Did you check if it's on the classpath twice, one of them being the older version?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you have to **remove**:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>    
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

becouse probably you imported ibernate-jpa-2.0-api or ibernate-jpa-2.1-api, indirectly too.

Answer (score -1):

This needs to be set as false:
`<prefer-web-inf-classes>**false**</prefer-web-inf-classes>`
if you're using:

> `<container-descriptor>`
>       `<prefer-application-packages>`
>           `<package-name>antlr.*</package-name>`
>           `<package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>`
>           `<package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>`
>       `</prefer-application-packages>`
>    `</container-descriptor>`