# How to get WLS-cat.war

Tags: weblogic-10.x

I am deploying an application on WebLogic 10.3 and getting an exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:190)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:486)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1466)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:898)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:686)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:539)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3027)
at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:341)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: weblogic.application.ModuleException: 
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1373)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:468)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:117)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:204)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:60)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:635)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:37)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:16)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:162)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:140)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:106)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:820)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1227)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:436)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:181)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:67)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getSharedCacheMode()Ljavax/persistence/SharedCacheMode;
at org.hibernate.ejb.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInfo(LogHelper.java:38)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:528)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:288)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1117)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:922)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:465)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
```

I tried all solutions to sort it out like [similar problem-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167945/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-spi-persistenceunitinfo-getvalida) and [similar problem-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520416/hibernate-weblogic-10-3-4-java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-spi-per).

The same solution I got at variouss other places, but due to some constraints, I couldnot apply them or they didn't work.

Now I need to use WLS-Cat for the application to check. but when I try to access

hostName:portNumber/wls-cat/. I couldnot access (error 404) I found from [oracle-blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/vtkrishn/entry/debugging_application_using_wls_cat) that I can find the wls-cat.war in WL_HOME/servers/bin/. But Its not there in the folder.

I searched to download this war. I found [this](http://northernserve.ca/downloads/Oracle/Middleware/). Im not sure what it is. Can somebody help me in finding this war file.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the WL_HOME/server/lib folder.
On windows it is in:
C:\Oracle\Middleware_11.1.2.4\wlserver_10.3\server\lib