# Method have no definition javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

My app throws this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in class path resource [datasource-tx-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:642)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 21 more
```

Please help me,
I use java 7, spring 4.0.0 and hibernate-jpa-2.1-api (version 1.0.0.Final)

Comment: Check that you actually have the jpa jar in your classpath

Comment: yes, I have dependeny in pom                                  <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
 <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0.Final</version>

Comment: I was talking about one which doesnt have hibernate in its name. Also check for the jar hibernate-validator

Comment: add jar and validator, the same error

Comment: hibernate core already have these jars, if using maven try with `mvn dependency:tree` so you can see what jars are available if with linux  adding `| grep hibernate` after **tree** will reduce result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two version of JPA API jar in your CLASSPATH and one is an earlier version (JPA 1.0). It finds the JPA 1.0 which doesn't have that method (since it was introduced in JPA 2.0). You should have only 1 version of JPA API jar to match your JPA implementation.

An internet search would have concluded the same.
[java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990633/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-javax-persistence-spi-persistenceunitinfo-getvalida)

http://www.coderanch.com/t/620558/ORM/databases/java-lang-NoSuchMethodError-javax-persistence

Answer (score 0):

That is not the correct Hibernate dependency. The only Hibernate dependencies you should need are as below (the 2nd only if you are using the validator):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version> <!-- change version if required-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.Final</version> <!-- change version if required-->
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I am not using validator and I have hibernate-entitymanager in pom

Comment: Ensure you have removed any other hibernate  dependency such as that you listed previously.

Comment: Also what server are you deploying to?

Comment: The issue is as advised by Neil however you will need to post your full pom  to see what is causing it.

Comment: Thank you Alan, the problem really was in JPA which had been added by GoogleAppEngine plugin in eclipse. When I ran jetty I didn't apply it. Now It work on both. But in pom i left dependency:  
   <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.Final</version>